# Protein misfolding

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, rna, literature-search, rna-structure

I am looking for literature on protein and RNA mis-folding. I am on the computational/biophysics side, and what interests me are the practical applications: diseases caused by misfolding, drug discovery, etc.

Comment: Protein mis-folding is a very interesting area right now @vadim

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elexacaftor/ivacaftor/tezacaftor

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question! I would recommend that you start with an NIH resource at the National Library of Medicine (NLM). PubMed (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) provides search capabilities across the biomedical literature. You can also create an account and use it to manage your searches of the literature. An example search below for "protein misfolding disease" in PubMed retrieved almost 50,000 hits. You can filter to make the results more specific to your interests. You can view the citations, including the abstracts, and often links to the full text. Since you mention that you are on the "computational/biophysics side," you might be interested in the PubMed API (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/developers/) and python modules that use the API, such as Biopython.

E-utilities:

> https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/

Biopython:

> https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html

PubMed Search:

> https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=protein%20misfolding%20disease

Specific Articles:

> https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/protein-misfolding-and-degenerative-diseases-14434929/
>   https://www.nature.com/articles/nrn1007